# Python: Combining multiple list in to the new one

Tags: python, list

Recently I have multiple lists in Python but don know how integrate in new one:

For example below:

```
ids = ['a','b','c','d','e']
p = [0.01, 0.02, 0.07, 0.04, 0.09]
qty = [10, 30, 50, 70, 90]
```

The desire result should be below:

```
combine =
[a, 0.01, 10]
[b, 0.02, 30]
[c, 0.07, 50]
[d, 0.04, 70]
[e, 0.09, 90]
```

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: You can make a list of tuples with `list(zip(ids, p, qty))`

Comment: `combine` is not valid Python data. You need something around all the lists.

Comment: @TomKarzes , I don't think `list(zip(ids, p, qty))` works , but  `[list(i) for i in zip(ids,p,qty)]` does.

Comment: @McLovin It works, except as I previously mentioned the result is a list of tuples (as opposed to a list of lists).  In fact someone wrote up my suggestion as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what the `zip()` operator is for:

```
>>> ids = ['a','b','c','d','e']
>>> p = [0.01, 0.02, 0.07, 0.04, 0.09]
>>> qty = [10, 30, 50, 70, 90]
>>> combine = list(zip(ids, p, qty))
>>> combine
[
 ('a', 0.01, 10),
 ('b', 0.02, 30),
 ('c', 0.07, 50),
 ('d', 0.04, 70),
 ('e', 0.09, 90)
]
```